# how to skip if attribute contains a specific string inside XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting all the XML data as child nodes in my c# code but i want to skip if any node starts with "MARK". Only the nodes without "MARK" as attribute should be processed. please help.

xml data

```
<AWE.ini> 
  <NOTICES name="MARK_AB1-1">
    <Type>
      CD
    </Type>
  </NOTICES>
  <NOTICES name="CGX1_CF-1">
    <Type>
      DF
    </Type>
  </NOTICES>
  <NOTICES name="CGX2_CF-2">
    <Type>
      DG
    </Type>
  </NOTICES>
  <NOTICES name="MARK_AB2-1">
    <Type>
      HJ
    </Type>
  </NOTICES>
</AWE.ini>
```

---

csharp code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("..\\AWE.xml");
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("AWE.ini/NOTICES");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    if (xn.HasChildNodes)
    {     
        foreach (XmlNode item in xn.ChildNodes)
        {
            m1.Type = xn.ChildNodes[0].InnerText.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you start with `doc.SelectNodes("AWE.ini/NOTICES")` instead of `doc.SelectNodes("AWE.ini/MARK")`?

Comment: yes. thank you. you are correct. this was just a sample code. so just written as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `String.Contains()` method (see; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your case the conditional statement would be like:

```
if (!m1.Type.Contains("MARK")) 
{
// your code
}
```

or alternatively:

```
if (!xn.ChildNodes[0].InnerText.ToString().Contains("MARK")) 
{
// your code
}
```

Also, `IndexOf()` method could be useful to check if `string1` contains `string2`. Usage:  `if(string1.IndexOf(string2)>=0)`

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add condition to your XPath, that checks value of `name` attribute.

```
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("AWE.ini/NOTICES[not(starts-with(@name, 'MARK'))]");
```

Only these two nodes will be returned:

```
<NOTICES name="CGX1_CF-1">
  <Type>
    DF
  </Type>
</NOTICES>
<NOTICES name="CGX2_CF-2">
  <Type>
    DG
  </Type>
</NOTICES>
```